# Linux cut fields from inside text line

Tags: shell, cut

I want to cut ;XXm m:;XXm from this lines:

```
Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context          ;XXm m:;XXm ENGINE-XXXXX Exception while
Xma.ExceptionLoggingFilter    ;XXm m:;XXm Uncaught exception thrown
Xmb.ExceptionHandlerController;XXm m:;XXm handle exception
```

This cuts whole line:

```
cut -d" " -f2,3
```

The result I want is:

```
Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context          ENGINE-XXXXX Exception while
Xma.ExceptionLoggingFilter    Uncaught exception thrown
Xmb.ExceptionHandlerController handle exception
```

or

```
Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context ENGINE-XXXXX Exception while 
Xma.ExceptionLoggingFilter Uncaught exception thrown
Xmb.ExceptionHandlerController handle exception
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/NanoInsidiousVirtualmemory#main.sh). Could be you have tabs not spaces in the file.

Comment: I want reverse result :), I want to cut ;XXm m:;XXm from this file, I don't want to have this text in result but everything apart from it. In description I added expected result.

Comment: `The result I want is:` You want to add a newline between `ENGINE-XXXX` and `Exception`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want reverse result :), I want to cut ;XXm m:;XXm from this fil

```
cut --complement -d" " -f2,3
```

or

```
cut -d" " -f1,4-
```

---

Learn about regexes.

```
sed 's/;XXm m:;XXm//'
```

Comment: Its working fine, but only for this one line, I added new lines to my description which this ;XXm m:;XXm to be cutted.

Comment: yeah :) sorry. Moreover this -f2,3 cuts only one space, not all of them

Comment: Edited. Use `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it it actually works:

```
[Alex@Normandy templates]$ echo "Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context ;XXm m:;XXm ENGINE-XXXXX BPMN Stack Trace:" | cut -d" " -f2,3 
;XXm m:;XXm
```

If you want reverse you can use Python like:

```
>>> x="Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context ;XXm m:;XXm ENGINE-XXXXX BPMN Stack Trace:"
>>> x_splited=x.split()
>>> " ".join(x_splited[:1]+x_splited[3:])
'Xmorg.camunda.bpm.engine.context ENGINE-XXXXX BPMN Stack Trace:'
```

Comment: I want reverse result :), I want to cut ;XXm m:;XXm from this file, I don't want to have this text in result but everything apart from it. In description I added expected result.

Comment: I add python solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you used the word "cut" in a misleading way.

```
cut -d" " -f1,4
```

This will extract exactly the first and fourth item from string